# Pull wall post from Facebook to external site?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using a permalink for a particular post, I would like that post to be displayed in its entirety within an iframe or a div tag. That is: likes, comments and shares and the Fb format for a post would all be displayed on an external site. Thus, a wall-post like this one https://www.facebook.com/cnn/posts/200591363341827 would appear exactly as is, except within my site.

Comment: Anyone??? :| Really struggling here...

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a div that represents a wall post and comments that relate to the topic at a URL link?

Refer to: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Also, look up other stuff that relates to social plugins at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exist as a plug in. You would need to write something yourself to pull all the data you want, and then display it on your page.